# Access to the path is denied in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, virtual-directory

I was trying to Create a Directory using this code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("localhost/attachments/7075");
```

But it returned `'Access to the path 'localhost/attachments/7075' is denied.'`

Please take note that the `attachments` is from a Network Shared Folder. I added it using the `Add Virtual Directory` on IIS.

What I did is:

- Tried to create a folder manually in the Shared Folder and I can.
- I tried to check the securities on folder the `IIS_IUsers` and it is in `Full Control`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Server.MapPath()` to use the physical file path that corresponds to the virtual path.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/attachments"), "7075"));
```